# how to add "target lists" to my custom module

Tags: sugarcrm

i have create a module and named: Custom_module by Developer Tools --> Module Builder
I trired to add "target lists" to Custom_module like module Campaign, but i can not find the way the do that
everyone can help you to find the best way to add "target lists" to my module.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You Just need to create a `custom  sub panel` in your `custom module`.
`target list` is `ProspectLists` module.

Follow this link to create custom module.

http://shanedowling.com/sugarcrm-7-custom-subpanels

https://developer.sugarcrm.com/2015/05/18/creating-subpanels-with-custom-results-in-sugar-7-5/

**1. Create a new link class**

This should go into **custom/modules//YourNewLink.php** and this class will act as the custom functionality that will build your link between the two records.

```
<?php

/**
 * Custom filtered link
 */
class YourNewLink extends Link2
{
    /**
     * DB
     *
     * @var DBManager
     */
    protected $db;

    public function __construct($linkName, $bean, $linkDef = false)
    {
        $this->focus = $bean;
        $this->name = $linkName;
        $this->db = DBManagerFactory::getInstance();
        if (empty($linkDef)) {
            $this->def = $bean->field_defs[$linkName];
        } else {
            $this->def = $linkDef;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns false if no relationship was found for this link
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function loadedSuccesfully()
    {
        // this link always loads successfully
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @see Link2::getRelatedModuleName()
     */
    public function getRelatedModuleName()
    {
        return '<Your_Module>';
    }

    /**
     *
     * @see Link2::buildJoinSugarQuery()
     */
    public function buildJoinSugarQuery($sugar_query, $options = array())
    {
        $joinParams = array('joinType' => isset($options['joinType']) ? $options['joinType'] : 'INNER');
        $jta = 'active_other_invites';
        if (!empty($options['joinTableAlias'])) {
            $jta = $joinParams['alias'] = $options['joinTableAlias'];
        }

        $sugar_query->joinRaw($this->getCustomJoin($options), $joinParams);
        return $sugar_query->join[$jta];
    }

    /**
     * Builds main join subpanel
     * @param string $params
     * @return string JOIN clause
     */
    protected function getCustomJoin($params = array())
    {
        $bean_id = $this->db->quoted($this->focus->id);
        $sql = " INNER JOIN(";
        $sql .= "SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE id={$bean_id}"; // This is essentially a select statement that will return a set of ids that you can match with the existing sugar_query
        $sql .= ") accounts_result ON accounts_result.id = sugar_query_table.id";
        return $sql;
    }
```

**2. Add a new vardef entry for the link field.**

For this example, I'm going to create the custom link on the contacts module. So this code goes in **custom/Extension/modules/Contacts/Ext/Vardefs/your_field_name.php**

```
<?php
$dictionary["Contact"]["fields"]["your_field_name"] = array(
    'name' => 'active_other_invites',
    'type' => 'link',
    'link_file' => 'custom/modules/<YourModule>/YourNewLink.php',
    'link_class' => 'YourNewLink',
    'source' => 'non-db',
    'vname' => 'LBL_NEW_LINK',
    'module' => '<YourModule>',
    'link_type' => 'many',
    'relationship' => '',
);
```

**3. Add the new link as a subpanel**

This goes under **custom/Extension/modules/Contacts/Ext/clients/base/layouts/subpanels/your_subpanel_name.php**

```
<?php
$viewdefs['Contacts']['base']['layout']['subpanels']['components'][] = array (
  'layout' => 'subpanel',
  'label' => 'LBL_NEW_LINK',
  'context' =>
  array (
    'link' => 'your_field_name',
  ),
);
```

**4. Add the label**

Under **custom/Extension/modules/Contacts/Ext/Language/en_us.new_link.php**

```
<?php
$mod_strings['LBL_ACTIVE_OTHER_INVITES'] = 'Your New Link';
```

**5. Quick Repair and Rebuild**

Comment: i have tried to flow you guide above, but it seem not work,
can you give me sample source code 
thanks

Comment: if you follow the first link , its give a step by step coding just need to add your module , i did it and its working for me.

Comment: Here my code
https://app.box.com/s/8d2so4q96js6c3zto0ln6om5qcuztpyn
i want to add "target lists" to my module.(like Campaigns)

Comment: you can do also , make a relation ship between your module and target list module, your subpanel will created automatically, but i did not found the target list module in code.

Comment: or just go through the campaigns module code you will find the way.